# Python Confluent AvroDeserializer - why is schema required?

Tags: python, avro, confluent-schema-registry

The Confluent AvroDeserializer requires the `schema_str`. However, I do not want to supply the schema, I just need to retrieve it from the registry, and that's it. What am I missing?

```
classconfluent_kafka.schema_registry.avro.AvroDeserializer(schema_str, schema_registry_client, from_dict=None)
```

Doc: https://docs.confluent.io/5.5.0/clients/confluent-kafka-python/index.html#avrodeserializer

Answer (score 0):

Avro requires a reader schema.

You can use the Registry client to fetch a schema string.

Comment: The AvroDeserializer directly interacts with the schema registry, so it does not make much sense to me to fetch the schema separately.

Comment: That'll extract the writer schema, embedded in the record, not a reader schema. Avro requires both. You can try passing None as the reader schema https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/blob/master/src/confluent_kafka/schema_registry/avro.py#L303

Comment: By the way, Java Kafka clients (or anything dealing directly with Avro bytes) also require 2 schemas.

Answer (score 0):

So it really is optional for Python `AvroDeserializer`; however, it is not (well) documented. The parameters are following:

```
classconfluent_kafka.schema_registry.avro.AvroDeserializer(schema_registry_client, schema_str=None, from_dict=None)
```

The PR making it optional is here:

https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/pull/1000

The related issue is here:

https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/834